# Something wrong with my Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

there's defenitely something wrong with my Laravel.

I have the Laravel 5.4 installed. I have installed Composer on my windows globally. I have `php artisan` working, but I'm getting errors everywhere:

---

**php artisan tinker**

When I type in `php artisan make:model Brand` it says `Model created succesfully.`
Awesome, right? When I type in `php artisan tinker` and `App/Brand::all()` next, it says Class 'Brand' not found.

While I have `Brand.php` inside my `app` folder:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brand extends Model
{
    //
}
```

---

By the way, I'm following [this series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/) at laracast.

---

**mySQL**

I can't run the `mysql` command, though I have manually installed mySQL on my windows (globally as well).

It says

```
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

---

**migrate**

`php artisan migrate` gives me this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key
length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key
length is 767 bytes
```

Besides this `php artisan migrate` is working very well, it creates two tables for me: *migrations* and *users*. I thought that was because I have two files in my `\database\migrations` folder. But...

When I say `php artisan make:migration create_brands_table --create=brands`, it creates a file inside this folder indeed. Like it should. I add a few lines inside the `up()` function so it looks like this:

```
Schema::table('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

But it does not create a table.

Please note that I did edit my `.env` file to make a proper database connection, otherwise `php artisan migrate` would not work on the other two tables I did create with the `php artsian migrate` command.

It only gives a alreadt exists error. I tried migrate:rollback and migrate:refresh as well. I tried doing this after the `composer dump-autoload` command, but it came with the same result.

---

I'm lost in the dark here, I am obviously new to Laravel, but some friends of mine who are familiar with Laravel have never experienced the problems I have.

---

I have tried to reinstall and create a new project and all... guess what: same results.

Comment: are you doing ```php artisan migrate`` again, after you write your brands migration?

Comment: "mySQL on my windows" Are you using WAMP or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got namespaces wrong, use **backslash**: `App\Brand`

To create a table use `Schema::create` and not `Schema::table`

The mysql part is not Laravel's concern and should not be in this question. Anyway you should check your environment PATH variable.

Comment: my backslash was the problem inside the Psy Shell indeed. But using `Schema::create` instead of `Schema::table` makes no difference. And my mysql commands are still not working.

Comment: The mysql part is not a Laravel's concern and should not be in this question.

Comment: Allright, well you'll have to understand that I am new to Laravel and did not know that. Thank you, though!

Comment: I assume that I can continue using Laravel without the use of mysql commands. Since I can manually do that.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the already existing table issue, I ran into that before and here's what I've done, first **delete your database file**, in my case I was using sqlite so my file was database.sqlite, I deleted that and **created** a new one(don't delete it permanently just in case), run your migrations normally to be sure everything is working for the normal tables, also delete your old Brand migration, then when you are creating a new migration for your Brands table, lose the `--create` flag,

Just like this `php artisan make:migration create_brands_table`, at this point do as mentioned before and use the `Schema::create` instead of `Schema::table`, hopefully everything should be working fine now.

Comment: And after that manually insert the Schema::create inside the new migration file?

Comment: Yeah just stub this in your up() method:

        Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Then run php artisan migrate and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow this seems to work fine... I wonder why I can't just do the same as the guide in the laracast videos, though! But this works fine.